# How to make Two Diagonal Lines background with CSS in opposite direction?

Tags: css

I know there are some questions on SO regarding this, but most that I find deal with background split in two colors. And I can't figure out how to customize that to fit what I'm trying to make.

I need a background like this:

[image]

And so far, whatever I tried, I can't seem to make it so that the other line goes in the opposite direction. Can someone help me out, please?

Here's what I got so far:

```css
.background {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #894325;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-78deg, #894325 70%, #e9e9e9 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
```

It doesn't look remotely as it should? Am I using the wrong approach or?
Thank you!

Comment: Would that work as a background?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? what you have is a background, I am only suggesting to do another background with it so you have 2 layers

Comment: Use two gradients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two gradients like :

```css
.background {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #894325;
  background: linear-gradient(172deg, rgba(137, 67, 37, 1) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(8deg, transparent 50%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 233) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, you can adjust positioning and colour as you see fit.
You can actually just use 1 element with multiple backgrounds. Note I have removed `background-color`

```css
.background {
  height: 400px;

  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-78deg, #894325 70%, transparent 30%), -webkit-linear-gradient(78deg, transparent 70%, red 30%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: top left, 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background2">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</div>
```